# center center css on dynamic heights

Tags: html, css

I want to put the play button (first img) centered to the second images. I can do it with position absolute and margin but how can that be dynamic? What if I'm in a loop and the height of the second images is not always the same?

```
<img src="http://maxcdn.clubcooee.com/img/icons/play-button2.png"/>
<img src="http://www.howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to do this

1) Put that image between paragraph tags and give style to that paragraph "text-align:center;", just like below

```html
<p style="text-align:center"><img src="#url to your image"/></p>
```

2) Give style to that img tags margin:0px auto , just like below

```html
 <img src="#url to your image" style="margin:0px auto;"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

you will need to add a parent for the images and position the play image absolute and set it top left 50% and set negative margin of half the width of the play image so that it align it vertically and horizontally

```css
div {
  margin: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
img.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -63px 0 0 -63px; 
}
.second .main {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<p>with smaller height</p>

<div>
  <img class="play" src="http://maxcdn.clubcooee.com/img/icons/play-button2.png" />
  <img class="main" src="http://www.howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg" />
</div>

<p>with larger height</p>

<div class="second">
  <img class="play" src="http://maxcdn.clubcooee.com/img/icons/play-button2.png" />
  <img class="main" src="http://www.howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: why hardcord margin -63px?

Comment: so that they work on older browsers if not you can use `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)`